# Can git diff report the exit code of an external diff program?

Tags: git, diff, exit-code

I know `git diff` can report a diff-like exit code, using the `--exit-code` option. However, I haven't found a way to make this play nicely with an external diff program. That is, I would like the external diff program to somehow be able to report back to git whether the files should be considered identical or not. Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

After some more research I learned that for my use case `difftool` works (as opposed to plain `diff`). Git difftool has a `trustExitCode` option (note: it's an option on `difftool`, not `difftool.<tool>`).